# Preg_replace Regex date

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble with preg_replace. My regex doesn't work. I have the following code :

```
$text = "<p><i>Dernière modification le 20/06/2016 à 10:27</i></p><p>Some text...</p>";
$preg = preg_replace("/<p><i>Dernière modification le[\s\d\/\:\à]{1,}<\/i><\/p>$/", '', $text);
```

I want to remove this line form the variable $text knowing that the date can change that's why I didn't use str_replace:

```
 <p><i>Dernière modification le 20/06/2016 à 10:27</i></p>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You should use a `/u` modifier when working with Unicode strings. You should also remove `$` since your required text is not at the end of the string. Have a look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/N4jE67).

Comment: You can use `<p><i>.*<\/i><\/p>` regex.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, your solution works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both regex and a DOMDocument way, looks like regex is kind of more staight-forward for this case (especially, if you are working with *strings* coming from a known, trustworthy provider):

```
//Regex way
$re = '/<p><i>Dernière modification le[\s\d\/:à]+<\/i><\/p>/u'; 
$str = "<p><i>Dernière modification le 20/06/2016 à 10:27</i></p><p>Some text...</p>"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
echo $result . "\n";

// DOMDocument way
$text = "<p><i>Dernière modification le 20/06/2016 à 10:27</i></p><p>Some text...</p>";
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//p/i[starts-with(.,"Dernière modification le")]');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
}
echo preg_replace('~(</?p>)+~', '$1', html_entity_decode($dom->saveHTML()));
```

See the [IDEONE  demo](https://ideone.com/lx6f8q)

With a regex, you should use a `/u` modifier when working with Unicode strings. You should also remove `$` since your required text is not at the end of the string.

When using a DOMDocument and an HTML Unicode string as input, you need to parse it, and then get the `p` that has `i` with the text starting with `Dernière modification le` (I suggest using an XPath like `'//p/i[starts-with(.,"Dernière modification le")]'`).